# Dryer plug burnt

Tags: dryer, cord-and-plug

I was using my dryer and it stopped working, when I went to unplug it, that's when I found out it had burnt and almost caused a house fire. It's not because of the radiator, as that's always switch off because of the plugs for my dryer and freezer. Is there anyway an new plug and socket fix it. Also anyone have any idea why this would have happened, as the dryer is no more than a year old.

[image]

Comment: It's VERY difficult to tell from that photo.  Is there any way you can take a better one?

Comment: yes, it is a terrible photo. In general, I *think* burnt plugs/sockets are usually just caused by loose plugs/sockets, rather than anything more sinister in the electrical wiring?

Comment: I will try and get a better picture, but I can't unplug it from the socket. With the melt plastic it is fused to the plug socket

Comment: Was it gas or electric?

Comment: I can't of overloaded the socket. It's a single socket extension cord

Comment: Using an extension cord might be part of the problem.  I would check to see if the extension is at least 14 or 12 gauge for high power use devices.  Quite a few extensions are only 16 gauge and too small.

Comment: What's the amperage  or KW of the dryer?

Comment: @JACK - "less than 13" always.

Comment: Is the extension cord quality product bought from a reputable local *bricks and mortar* shop in your jurisdiction?  A whole ton of unsafe garbage is sold mail order, including through Amazon Marketplace (ships from Amazon's warehouse but it's a 3rd party seller importing cheap Cheese junk).  However, the developed countries do a pretty good job of keeping that crud out of reputable retail stores like Wickes, Redoute or Home Depot.

Answer (score 5):

You've obviously overloaded the socket or bought a really cheap extension chord and it overheated/arced and melted everything together. Dryers are high users of electricity and usually need a dedicated outlet properly installed, not sharing sockets on cheap extension cords.

You can probably get a replacement cord from the manufacturer and disconnect the old one from inside the dryer. If you're not comfortable doing this, get an appliance repair tech to do the work. You could also cut off the old plug and replace it with a properly rated one. Then use only rated outlets/sockets as described in the instruction manual for the dryer.

Comment: I'd bet it's the cheap socket sparking, not the plug or actual load. British extensions, so long as you avoid the cheap sh… er...stuff on Amazon/eBay are quite up to this task, & the manufacturer/distributor of the appliance is compelled to use a correctly rated & approved plug.

Comment: @Tetsujin  You're probably right on the cheap socket.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, this isn't an overload, it's a cheap socket sparking because it's not making a clean connection.

Go to B&Q, not Amazon or eBay & get a new 13A plug & *all* new extensions. I would no longer trust any you still have. Clip the old plug off its cable & replace. Make sure the extensions are rated at 13A not 10A - those cables look suspiciously thin for 13A.

Don't run more than one extension from each wall socket & don't plug more than one high-usage appliance in each extension. The highest likelihood is the cheap extension caused the sparking, not the plug or appliance.

Cheap extensions are not worth the money.